# "react-google-login" package is deprecated what is to be the replacement for the new package in Oauth 2.0?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, oauth, google-oauth, react-google-login

recently google has deprecated the npm package "react-google-login" and replaced it by "react-oauth/google". I have tried to use the new package but after pressing the google button the google sign-in page disapear without actually redirecting the page to the profile directory.

```
import { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { FcGoogle } from "react-icons/fc";
import { MdVisibility } from "react-icons/md";
import { MdVisibilityOff } from "react-icons/md";
import { isEmpty, isEmail } from "../helper/validate";
import axios from "axios";
import { ToastContainer, toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import Input from "../Input/Input";
import "./login.css";
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
//import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login"; //deprecated
import { GoogleLogin } from '@react-oauth/google';

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  password: "",
};

const Login = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const [data, setData] = useState(initialState);
  const { email, password } = data;
  const { dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  const login = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // check fields
    if (isEmpty(email) || isEmpty(password))
      return toast("Please fill in all fields.", {
        className: "toast-failed",
        bodyClassName: "toast-failed",
      });
    // check email
    if (!isEmail(email))
      return toast("Please enter a valid email address.", {
        className: "toast-failed",
        bodyClassName: "toast-failed",
      });
    try {
      await axios.post("/api/auth/signing", { email, password });
      localStorage.setItem("_appSignging", true);
      dispatch({ type: "SIGNING" });
    } catch (err) {
      toast(err.response.data.msg, {
        className: "toast-failed",
        bodyClassName: "toast-failed",
      });
    }
  };

  const googleSuccess = async (res) => {
    const token = res?.tokenId;
    try {
      await axios.post("/api/auth/google_signing", { tokenId: token });
      localStorage.setItem("_appSignging", true);
      dispatch({ type: "SIGNING" });
    } catch (err) {
      toast(err.response.data.msg, {
        className: "toast-failed",
        bodyClassName: "toast-failed",
      });
    }
  };

  const googleError = () => {
    toast("There was an error signing in, please try again later.", {
      className: "toast-failed",
      bodyClassName: "toast-failed",
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ToastContainer />
      <form className="login" onSubmit={login}>
        <Input
          type="email"
          text="Email"
          name="email"
          handleChange={handleChange}
        />
        <Input
          name="password"
          type={visible ? "text" : "password"}
          icon={visible ? <MdVisibility /> : <MdVisibilityOff />}
          text="Password"
          handleClick={handleClick}
          handleChange={handleChange}
        />
        <div className="login_btn">
          <button type="submit">login</button>
          <GoogleLogin
            clientId={process.env.REACT_APP_G_CLIENT_ID}
            render={(renderProps) => (
              <button
                className="btn-alt"
                onClick={renderProps.onClick}
                disabled={renderProps.disabled}
              >
                sign in <FcGoogle />
              </button>
            )}
            cookiePolicy={"single_host_origin"}
            onSuccess={googleSuccess}
            onFailure={googleError}
          />
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

how can I modify my code to sign-in with this new Oauth 2.0 system?

Answer (score 1):

both **Authorized JavaScript origins** and **Authorized redirect URIs**  should include the backend and the frontend URL address.
there is a youtube clip that explains this problem in detail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SODClEHLeCA

Answer (score 1):

To better understand Google's answer to the "what is replacing it?" question, check out:

- [HTML API Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference),
- [JavaScript API Reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference),

One potential way in react (although open to better ways):

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const LoginWithGoogle = () => {

  useEffect(() => {

    window.onGoogleSuccess = (response) => {
      // hit your backend, passing up response.credential
    }

    // Inject the google provided script 
    // (an importable module would be nicer here)
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      // clean up for react lifecycle
      window.onGoogleSuccess = undefined;
      document.body.removeChild(script)
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div id="g_id_onload"
        data-client_id={"PUT_YOU_CLIENT_ID_HERE"}
        data-callback="onGoogleSuccess" // as defined above
        data-context="signin"
        data-ux_mode="popup"
        data-auto_prompt="false">
      </div>

      <div className="g_id_signin"
        data-type="standard"
        data-shape="rectangular"
        data-theme="filled_blue"
        data-text="signin_with"
        data-size="large"
        data-logo_alignment="left">
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

If going this route, you can check out
[Google's HTML generator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator) to quickly customize it.